# how to create a singleton class and how to use it in EXJS

Tags: extjs

I have the following singleton class, which i thinki have create correctly.  i have tried to retrieve a value from it but I keep getting a return value of undefined. please can somone advise?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.PdfDrawRect', {
singleton: true,
config: {
    zoomValue: 1
},
constructor: function (config) {
    this.initConfig(config);
    return this;
},

setZoomValue: function (value) {
    console.log('setZoomValue');
    MyApp.PdfDrawRect.zoomValue = value;


},

getZoomValue: function () {
    console.log('getZoomValue');
    return this.zoomValue;
}
});
```

usage

MyApp.getZoomValue() // this return 'undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyApp.getZoomValue() is an undefined function because there is an undefined object named MyApp.  There are two levels in the fully qualified object name.

The first line instantiates the class object.  The second line calls a function for that class object.

```
var theObject = Ext.create('MyApp.PdfDrawRect');
theObject.getZoomValue();
```

or

```
var MyApp1 = Ext.create('MyApp.PdfDrawRect');
MyApp1.getZoomValue();
```

---

Question in comment:

What you have built was a config.  There are also properties in ExtJS.  They are similar but different.  Search for ExtJS examples of properties and how to build a getter and setter.

> configs - are passed in the constructor, which defines behavior of the
> class, configs should not be changed at run-time because it will not
> have any effect, suppose you need to specify a title for the panel
> then you can add a config e.g. { title : 'some title' } that will be
> used by panel to set title of the panel at render time, but after
> that, even if you try to change title, you can't alter the property by
> simply changing that config option.
>
> properties - are used to store information which is useful for that
> class, this is normally not passed through constructor but should have
> getter and setter methods, you can change property at run-time (if
> setter method is defined) and class object should detect this change,
> there can be read only properties also which are modified by class
> object only we shouldn't change it all.

https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/guides/core_concepts/classes.html

Look how the property 'name' is defined in the code block under "Declaration" section in the link.

Once you have the name property, you can call the default setter like so:

```
theObject.name = 'JohnDoe';
```

And call the getter like so:

```
nameVal = theObject.name;
```

Or you can override a getter or setter by building your own function.  But the function cannot be a custom name like you have.

On the other hand, you can keep these as configs.  See this example.  You can mimic getters and setters using configs instead of properties.

https://www.extjs-tutorial.com/extjs/config

Comment: please can i ask if i have written the setter and getter correctly?

Comment: Take a look in the link at the very end of my answer.  Both properties and configs have ways of dealing with getters and setters, but in different ways.

Comment: sorry, I reversed the getter and setter in my answer.  I just swapped them.

Answer (score 0):

In your case i recommend you to use `this` in `setZoomValue`:

```
setZoomValue: function() {
   if(!this.getZoomValue()) {
       this.zoomValue = true;
   }
}
```

You can add additional (alternative) class names to call singleton's methods in your application.

```js
Ext.define('SomeApp.somefolder.RoleAdapter', {
   singleton: true,
    alternateClassName: [
        'RA', 'RoleAdapter'
    ],
  
   addRoleToUser: function(role) {
      console.log('role added');
   },
  
   isAdmin: function() {
      return true;
   }
});
```

also you can require it in your application (to allow use it in any part of application)

```
Ext.define('SomeApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    name: 'SomeApp',
    requires: ['SomeApp.somefolder.RoleAdapter'],
    ....
});
```

and use your class everywhere you want to

```
...
xtype: 'textfield',
hidden: RoleAdapter.isAdmin() // or RA.isAdmin()
...
```

or

```
myNewFunction: function() {
    RoleAdapter.addRoleToUser({roleId: 1, isAdmin: false}) // or RA.add...
}
```